# Using an Emission shader with textures without affecting the color of the mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I am using an image texture node as input to the emission node's color (basically, the texture controls the color of the emission).

Unfortunately, when I turn up the brightness of the emission node, the rendered mesh gets brighter and brighter until it's solid white.

I want the color of the mesh to stay the same but the light cast off by it to get brighter, is this possible do? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mix an emission shader with emission value `1` with an emission shader with a higher value based on the *is camera ray* output of the *light path* node.  This way the camera will get the actual value with everything else getting the higher value.

[image]