# Make strength of emmision independent from the surface brightness

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, light

[image: animated gif]

How can I make that sphere glow less but still keep the luminance. I've tried to mess around with the options but without results.

[image]

Comment: I assume you are using cycles, is that correct?

Comment: If it is cycles, you simply need the light path node, use the is camera ray option

Comment: I have no clue what you are saying about cycles.

Comment: http://imgur.com/hfBD0dU

Comment: Here you can see my settings. I also have other settings on the World tab

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42803/how-to-make-mesh-lights-brighter-without-washing-out-in-the-render/

Comment: Okay i changed the render mode to Cycles , but now i lost all colour. Please help. This looks cool

Comment: Yeah, Cycles can't use the same materials as BI, so Cycles just defaults to a flat gray material. You could use Cycles, but you'd have to remake all your materials. It's not hard, but you'd have to learn Cycles.

Comment: Look into filmic Blender as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9AT7H4GGrA

Answer (score 2):

With the Blender Internal renderer, it's not very easy, but it is doable.

The basic idea is to render the glowing ball twice, and composite the dimmer one over the brighter one.

Keep everything you have so far, but investigate how to render just the ball. The basics are, move it to its own layer and set up a second set of render layers that gives you only the ball, with nothing else in the scene at all.

More on Render Layers from [the Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html):

> Each Render Layer has an associated set of Scene Layers. Objects which are on one of the associated Scene Layers are shown in that Render Layer, as long as that Scene Layer is also visible.
>
> **Warning**
> Only the objects in visible Scene Layers will be rendered. So, if only Scene Layer 1 is visible and your Render Layer set specifies to render only Layers 2 and 3, nothing will be rendered.

Once you have those two renders happening at the same time, you will use the compositor to put the dimmer ball (that's all by itself) over top of the image that has everything in it. You'll use an Alpha Over node to combine the two.

More on the Alpha Over node in [the Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/color/alpha_over.html):

> Use this node to layer images on top of one another. Alpha Over does not work on the colors of an image.
>
> [image: Alpha Over Node]

Doing this with Cycles is much simpler, but Cycles **does not use the same materials as BI.** You will have to make your materials again, as Cycles materials. That's why everything doesn't have any color when you just change renderers. Cycles is using a default gray material.

Comment: For cycles read this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/make-the-flame-of-a-candle-more-yellow

Answer (score 1):

I might have another answer and one that takes only a minute or so to put in place.

Just place a "Point"lamp inside the sphere and parent it to the sphere.

Wind up the lamp's strength if need be, and make the sphere's surface as dull and as dark as you like.

I've got the lamp's strength wound up a bit to exaggerate the effect.

Adjust the cube's (and surrounds) specular to whatever colour and reflectivity is required.

Please note - this was rendered using 'OpenGL'.  The noise (banding) you see on the cube occurs after the gif animation and compression, not Blender's video.

[image]