# How to make my created object to be bright just like a monitor

Tags: modeling

Hello I am trying to create a PC monitor with a texture displayed on the screen. Now when I render, texture is displayed on the screen, but it look dark. I want to make it brighter without using a lamp like sun.

Here is the image when I render it.

[image]

And I'm just a newbie I don't know this thing right here:

[image]

And I tried this thing right here:

[Using an Emission shader with textures without affecting the color of the mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39471/using-an-emission-shader-with-textures-without-affecting-the-color-of-the-mesh)

Comment: It's working fine here. Check your normals maybe? Or upload .blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: here's the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3668" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3668/)

Comment: You're using a Diffuse shader. You should be using the Emission shader

Comment: Remove that Light Path node, then connect the Image Texture Color output to the Factor input of the Mix Shader. Swap Emission Shaders if necessary.

Comment: you're right about the emission shader thank you